# Saving user input for the duration of the program

Tags: c#, .net, variables, client

I was wondering how could I save the user input for the duration of the program.

**My Code:**

```
struct client
{
    public string points;//to collect the points from a textbox

    public int  x;//variable used to temporarily save the input from the textbox
    public int will;//used to store his points until the end of the program
    public int steph;//used to store here points until the end of the program
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      client ob = new client();//instance of client
      ob.points = textBox1.Text;             
      ob.x  = Convert.ToInt32(ob.points);//conversion
      MessageBox.Show(ob.x.ToString());//used to confirm points
      button1.Enabled = true;//enables button to show where the points should go
      button2.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client ob = new client();
        ob.points = textBox1.Text;           
        ob.x = Convert.ToInt32(ob.points);
        ob.will = ob.will + ob.x;
        MessageBox.Show(ob.will.ToString());//actually adding the points to him
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        client ob = new client();
        ob.points = textBox1.Text;
        ob.x = Convert.ToInt32(ob.points);
        ob.steph = ob.steph + ob.x;// actually adding the points to her
        MessageBox.Show(ob.steph.ToString());
    }
}
```

I was told I need to add three instances of my client but that is all the information they gave me.  When you tell me can you please be in depth in your answer. Also If there is a way to make the code more efficient please tell me.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are asking. If you have three clients running at the same time, do you need to share these values between those clients? Or do you just need to know how to keep the values in memory for each client separately?

Comment: Looks like your asking about a [singleton class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

Comment: I was asking how to make a variable run for the duration of the program.  When I enter the value and select which user  to give points to it just erases the old value instead of saving it

Comment: @user2636646 Try using `static`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is

```
client ob = new client();//instance of client
```

This line makes a *new* instance of client every time, what you are looking for is singleton class

```
public sealed class Client
{
   private static readonly Client instance = new Client();

   private Client(){}

   public static Client Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         return instance; 
      }
   }
   public int  X {get;set;}
}
```

then whenever you need your client you call

```
Client.Instance
Clienet.Instance.X
```

and so on..

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) for more information

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question, i think you can use global class variable .
It can be:
`List<Client> clients` and than you will add after each button click new client to the global `List<Client>`

Comment: **do not** use global variables, its awful programming